# How do I disable keyboard autorepeat?

Tags: keyboard

How do I disable the keyboard feature whereby holding down a key causes it to start automatically repeating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu with Unity you can open Dash type System Settings then click on Keyboard and uncheck the **Key presses repeat when key is hold down** option

Comment: I can't fond it. I don't know why. I use 12.10.

Comment: oh, I fond it.;D